# Sending SpringBoot / Sleuth Zipkin Traces to Honeycomb.io

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-sleuth, zipkin, opentracing

Sending traces from an existing instrumented Spring Boot application to [honeycomb-opentracing-proxy](https://github.com/honeycombio/honeycomb-opentracing-proxy) is failing with the following error in the proxy console:

```
time="2019-10-25T02:51:55Z" level=info msg="error unmarshaling spans" error="json: cannot unmarshal bool into Go struct field binaryAnnotation.value of type string" type=application/json
```

Spring Boot Version: 2.1.3.RELEASE
Spring Cloud Sleuth Version: 2.1.1.RELEASE

Running the open tracing proxy with the following docker command:

```
docker run -p 9411:9411 honeycombio/honeycomb-opentracing-proxy -k $KEY -d $DATA_SET
```

From reading the documentation [here](https://docs.honeycomb.io/working-with-your-data/tracing/send-trace-data/) the honeycomb-opentracing-proxy only supports v1 of the JSON API so I have explicitly set that in spring cloud config as this appears to default to v2.

application.properties

```
spring.zipkin.sender.type=web
spring.zipkin.base-url=http://localhost:9411
spring.zipkin.enabled=true
spring.zipkin.encoder=json_v1
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

probably best to have the issue you raised in github vs cross posting. it is a bug https://github.com/honeycombio/honeycomb-opentracing-proxy/issues/37